# Java Rename File

Tags: java, файлы, io

Я пытаюсь из метода main изменить имя файла которы находится у меня в проекте:Вот код

```
File file=new File("src/com/company/stdPackage/Barnsley.java");

  if(file.renameTo(new File("src/com/company/stdPackage/RenameTesting.java"))){

      System.out.println("succes");

  } else{
      System.out.println("failed");
  }
```

Но у меня получается как указано на картинке,как сделать так чтобы просто изменилось имя файла не затрагивая ничего другого?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы переименовываете файл, а название класса, находящегося в этом файле остаётся прежним, поэтому среда так отображает.

Comment: понятно спасибо,значит в случае .java файлов оно всегда так и будет отображаться если не переименовать и сам класс,но другие файлы ,текстовые,картинки и так далее должны измениться нормально я правильно понял?